# Can I generate AVX vectorized code using LLVM jit?

Tags: x86, llvm, jit, avx

I understand I can set mcpu and mattr in EngineBuilder to generate vectorized code.
But I find the clang front has to involve for AVX using -mavx. Otherwise the generated assembly uses only xmm register.

Is there a way to let LLVM know 8 floating numbers can be put in an AVX register without front end involved?

---

My testing code is just vector adding:

```
float a[N], b[N];
float c[N];
// initialize a and b
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Yes. You just need to call `opt` and tell it to vectorize your code.

You can most definitely do it without clang. The vectorizers are all about LLVM IR, they're not in clang.

I got this IR from your example by using clang without optimizations (yeah, I cheated, and then annotated a bit or two):  (data layout and triple are important!)

```
target datalayout = "e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0"

define float* @f(i32 %N, float* nocapture readonly %a, float* nocapture readonly %b, float* %c) {
entry:
  %cmp10 = icmp sgt i32 %N, 0   ; check for early exit
  br i1 %cmp10, label %for.body, label %for.end

for.body:                                         ; preds = %entry, %for.body
  %indvars.iv = phi i64 [ %indvars.iv.next, %for.body ], [ 0, %entry ]

  %arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds float* %a, i64 %indvars.iv
  %0 = load float* %arrayidx, align 4     ; %0 = a[i]
  %arrayidx2 = getelementptr inbounds float* %b, i64 %indvars.iv
  %1 = load float* %arrayidx2, align 4    ; %1 = a[i]

  %add = fadd float %0, %1                ; %add = %0 + %1

  %arrayidx4 = getelementptr inbounds float* %c, i64 %indvars.iv
  store float %add, float* %arrayidx4, align 4   ; c[i] = %add

  %indvars.iv.next = add nuw nsw i64 %indvars.iv, 1
  %lftr.wideiv = trunc i64 %indvars.iv.next to i32
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %lftr.wideiv, %N       ; test for loop exit
  br i1 %exitcond, label %for.end, label %for.body

for.end:                                          ; preds = %for.body, %entry
  ret float* %c
}
```

Now you want to vectorize the code. Let's run it through the loop vectorizer, then.

```
opt a.ll -S -march=x86-64 -mcpu=btver2 -loop-vectorize
```

(I ran it with `-S` to get the output at the console)

Now we have vectorized IR with a huge `vector.body`, as well as some checks, preheader, and additional bookkeeping code. You'll see this in the middle of the file:

```
  %171 = getelementptr inbounds float* %b, i64 %98
  %172 = insertelement <8 x float*> %170, float* %171, i32 7
  %173 = getelementptr float* %109, i32 0
  %174 = bitcast float* %173 to <8 x float>*
  %wide.load18 = load <8 x float>* %174, align 4
  %175 = getelementptr float* %109, i32 8
  %176 = bitcast float* %175 to <8 x float>*
  %wide.load19 = load <8 x float>* %176, align 4
  %177 = getelementptr float* %109, i32 16
  %178 = bitcast float* %177 to <8 x float>*
  %wide.load20 = load <8 x float>* %178, align 4
  %179 = getelementptr float* %109, i32 24
  %180 = bitcast float* %179 to <8 x float>*
  %wide.load21 = load <8 x float>* %180, align 4
  %181 = fadd <8 x float> %wide.load, %wide.load18
  %182 = fadd <8 x float> %wide.load15, %wide.load19
  %183 = fadd <8 x float> %wide.load16, %wide.load20
  %184 = fadd <8 x float> %wide.load17, %wide.load21
  %185 = getelementptr inbounds float* %c, i64 %5
  %186 = insertelement <8 x float*> undef, float* %185, i32 0
```

It's a bit complicated, but most of the floating point additions (`fadd`) are there, and only done on vectors. Let's make it simpler and run the other optimizations with `-O2` or `-O3`. This will make the IR smaller and simpler by removing and/or collapsing parts of it that wouldn't be needed or profitable.

```
opt a.ll -S -march=x86-64 -mcpu=btver2 -loop-vectorize -O3
```

Well… Since we now have IR that already works on vectors, we just need to emit it. Let's take that last step, and call `llc`:

```
opt a.ll -S -march=x86-64 -mcpu=core-avx2 -loop-vectorize -O3 | llc -mcpu=core-avx2
```

Looking at the disassembly, you have a tight inner loop (if you have the same names as me, this should be label `LBB0_5`), and a bunch of bookkeeping code.

Your code is now vectorized.

Answer (score -1):

No FE involved, only LLVM itself:

```
llc -mattr=+avx -O3 test.il
```

PS
You can generate test.il from your C-code by

```
clang -S -emit-llvm test.c
```

Comment: Thank for your tips. But I have tried this on a trunk version LLVM before(Mar 21 2014). Without the help of clang, something like [8 x float] will not generated in the IR. And LLVM can not recognize that two [4 x float] can be a [8 x float].

Comment: @TheBusyTypist, you need [autovectorization](http://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html) to generate and fold vector types. You also have to provide correct triple/-march values for your target.

Comment: `llc` doesn't run the vectorization passes. If you're seeing vector instructions it's most likely because you're (I assume) running code on an x86-64 machine, which has an ABI that says to use SSE/AVX registers for floating point code. But it's still scalar code: it should be using only *ss (adds, movss, etc) instructions.

Comment: @filcab, llc does run the vectorization pass in fact. Use `-O2` (or `-Ofast`) and `-debug-only=loop-vectorize` to see the vectorizer logs. Also add `-march=core-avx2`

Comment: @ZinovyNis: Are you really using `llc`? `llc` doesn't accept `-Ofast`. -march=core-avx2 is invalid (it's -mcpu=core-avx2), `-debug-only=loop-vectorize` doesn't add anything to the output and it doesn't vectorize the code. As I said, it actually uses the xmm registers, because that's what the ABI says. But it's still only doing one float at a time. Are you sure you're not thinking about `opt` and `llc` together?

Comment: @filcab sorry, confused with opt.